# Input voltage range of OPA551 Op amp

Tags: amplifier

I'm using OPA551 op-amp and I was reading the data sheet. It says that 
input voltage range        min((V-)-0.5V)        max((V+)+0.5V)

I don't get what it means. Does it mean that 5VAC is the maximum voltage for both (+) and (-) an op-amp?

Comment: You are right -0.5 and +0.5. What does it mean?

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: You left out the parts that actually make the question make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the abs max input voltage specified as follows: (V–) – 0.5 (V+) + 0.5. That means you can exceed either supply rail by no more than 0.5V.

For example, if you are supplying +/- 12V to the amplifier, the abs max input range is 12.5V and -12.5V.  That doesn't mean that the amplifier will meet the datasheet specs in the region outside the recommended operating conditions, but it does mean that you won't damage it.

The input common mode range is specified as (V–) + 2.5 (V+) – 2.5.  So for proper operation as an amplifier you should observe that constraint, which is obviously much different from the abs max rating.

Comment: And to clarify, with +/-12V supplies, that means keep the inputs within -9.5 to +9.5V.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, does it mean that I can have 2.5 V going into the non-inverting input and -2.5V to the inverting input?

Comment: Note the common mode range is only specified at 25°C Tj, so it might be prudent to allow a bit more than 2.5V to each rail.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the internal protection diodes will turn on at 0.5 volts higher and lower than the rails. I think this would have become evident had you read the whole datasheet. Yes you have to kind of read between the lines, but its easy to figure out why if you draw a schematic in your head of the input terminals.

> 7.3.3 Input Protection The OPA55x features internal clamp diodes to protect the inputs when voltages beyond the supply rails are
>   encountered. However, input current must be limited to 5 mA. In some
>   cases, an external series resistor may be required. Many input signals
>   are inherently current-limited; therefore, a limiting resistor may not
>   be required. Consider that a large series resistor, in conjunction
>   with the input capacitance, can affect stability.

INPUT IMPEDANCE
Differential 10e13Ω || 2 pF
Common-mode 10e13Ω || 6 pF

Here is the input impedance, from these two things you can build a model of the inputs

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f20XLL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The 0.5V outside supply rails is an ABSOLUTE MAX spec to prevent burning out 5mA Schottky clamp diodes on inputs used for ESD protection.

The 2.5V offset "inside" the supply rails is a functional limitation.

This device with high current is best suited for bipolar supplies +/-4Vmin and CM input or V-in =V+in must be at least 2.5V (inside) away from supply rails for input bias to function but performs better in other respects for Rail to Rail input Op Amps.

That may sound like a restriction, but that is needed for low input offset with laser trim, very low noise and high slew rate at 200mA out.